# Problema de autenticação com Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Eu estou usando o Firebase para autenticação e banco de dados do meu app, estava tudo perfeitamente bem até (vou falar exatamente o que aconteceu pois não sei se tem relação ou não) eu começar a mexer no mapa que tem no app, tentando implementar um PlaceAutocompleteAdapter, aí eu adicionei tal api e restringi o acesso. Quando eu vi o Firebase tinha desconectado do app, aí eu conectei e fiz o que ele pediu, mas quando fui testar a autenticação deu esse erro

**BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for**

Eu consigo escrever no DB, só a autenticação que falha

```
 FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance;

 //Ao clicar no botão de registrar
 auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password){

 }
```

Comment: Como você está fazendo a conexão com o Firebase? Está utilizando Firebase Auth ou Firebase Database para autenticação?

Comment: consegui, o problema é que eu tinha duas chaves SHA-1 registradas nas configurações (n sei pq), aí eu excluí a desnecessária e funcionou